# How do you solve a "compilation unit is not of SOURCE kind" error in intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While running a build in intelliJ and you get this error, but not in MAVEN on the command line..

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the case of your source file extension is .java an not .Java

I couldn't find it anywhere online so i thought i'd leave it here for posterity.